# repositioning a positional argument that follows a keyword argument from flask megatutorial

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

having a syntax error with this block of code:

```
followed = db.relationship(
    'User', secondary=followers,
    primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
    secondaryjoin(followers.c.followed_id == id),
    backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

eliminating the bit of syntax the core problem is I'm not sure why 2 "lazy = 'dynamic' " are needed. I partially understand why it is a syntax error but don't understand how to fix it

Comment: I was right about the syntax error, just not where. You're missing `=` after `secondaryjoin`

Comment: first `lazy` is setting for loading from `User.followers` (this is what backref relationship is), second `lazy` is for `Obj.followed` relationship.

Comment: thank you guys for helping with this issue